# What happens to the dynamic temperature in the boundary layer at supersonic speed?

Tags: airfoil, temperature

In the boundary layer for a supersonic flow, does the dynamic temp decrease?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you :) I changed the question

Comment: related: [How can dynamic and static pressure be explained?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36656/how-can-dynamic-and-static-pressure-be-explained)

Comment: This question shows no research.